# Can someone explain the difference between different kinds of malts?

Tags: malt

I'm just getting into brewing and I'm curious what kinds of Malts are out there and what I can expect from them. I made an IPA for my first batch, which seems to be conditioning well so far, and I'm trying to decide what I should try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save reinventing the wheel, take a look at this...

http://byo.com/resources/grains